# Is there no law which includes an addition of different types quantities?

Tags: soft-question, units, education

I haerd that we cannot add two different types quantities.

Is there no law which includes an addition of different types quantities?

In the future, maybe we find a law like this $$F = \frac{\alpha}{r+m_1 m_2}.$$

Comment: I don't think it's _a law_, but it's simply not consistent. Can you tell me what is the result of adding 3kg to 3cm³?

Comment: You may also be interested in https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/98241/25301

Answer (score 0):

There is no law in which different type quantities are added, and we're not going to find any such law in the future. It simply makes no sense to add two quantities with different physical dimensions, such as "1 meter plus 1 second".

Comment: While it does not make any sense, the real question is *why* it does not make sense. What makes physics a strongly typed theory?